# Bootstrap - change color panel-primary

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, panel

I have used panel-primary to make a panel in Bootstrap. But now I want to change the default blue color.

I have added the css, but with this change the panel keeps the blue color

```
#panel-primary {
background-color: #194719;
```

}

How can I change this blue color?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`panel-primary` is a class.

You will need to do it like this:

```
.panel-primary {
     background-color: #194719 !important;
}
```

Replace the `#` before `panel-primary` with a `.` (leave the `#` on the colour as is)

The `#` is used when you reference an element ID in CSS. A `.` will reference a class.

Comment: You are right. That was a mistake. But when I change it, the panel is still blue.

Comment: You are either trying to change the colour of the wrong class or the css is being overridden. I have updated my answer with an extra `!important`. Ideally you would need to post your HTML for us to see as well.

Comment: It's fixed. I was indeed trying to change the colour of the wrong class. The right class name is: panel-heading. Thanks for your help.